# DeleteFolder removes file contents but not folder

Tags: vbscript

I want to send the contents of a folder in an email and then delete the folder and the contents.

The code below works, except that it deletes only the contents of the folder and then gives me a Run-time error 70 - Permission denied and leaves the folder. The DeleteAFolder sub works if I run it separately and define strFolder. So it seems that it's somehow an issue of something still being in use, but I can't figure what or how to close it. It's only an empty folder that I can't delete. The files have already been sent in the email and deleted.

```
Sub SendMultiDocsEmail()

strFolder = "C:\Users\UserID\Desktop\Admin"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

Set objMessage = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
objMessage.Subject = "Testing my files email"
objMessage.From = "myemail@company.com"
objMessage.To = "myemail@company.com"
objMessage.TextBody = "This is a test, files should be attached to this email."
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    strFileExt = objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path)
    objMessage.AddAttachment objFile.Path
    'objFile.Close
    ' Run-time error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method
Next

'Configuration Info
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
'Name or IP of Remote SMTP Server
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "mail.company.com"
'Server port (typically 25)
objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Item _
    ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25

objMessage.Configuration.Fields.Update
objMessage.Send

'strFolder.Close
' Run-time error 424 - Object required
'objFolder.Close
' Run-time error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method

'Tried adding the Set to Nothing lines - didn't change result
'Set objFSO = Nothing
'Set objFolder = Nothing

DeleteAFolder (strFolder)
End Sub


Sub DeleteAFolder(strFolder)
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
fso.DeleteFolder (strFolder)
End Sub
```

Comment: Release the `objMessage` object after sending.`set objMessage = Nothing`

Comment: Thank you! That did it easily after I spent much time previously trying to sort it out. Never would have thought that an already sent message would still be linked to an empty folder and prevent it from being deleted.